# No call stack information in VTune GUI

Tags: intel-vtune

I'm trying to run a hotspot analysis on Ubuntu and I see no callstack info. I'm getting few warnings after data is collected.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only user-mode sampling collects stacks by default. In H/W event based sampling you have to explicitly check that option. Please confirm that you have enabled the collect stack option.
Also, try to run vtune self checker script which is available in vtune installed directory. This script is to validate whether the appropriate drivers are installed and system is set up properly to collect performance data.
You can find vtune-self-checker.sh script in /bin64.